# regexp length dependent on contents

Tags: regex, matlab, vectorization

Background: I am using MATLAB and opening large files with long strings of hexadecimal represented in ASCII text. The MATLAB script interprets this text based on patterns. I have successfully utilized bsxfun, cellfun, and arrayfun with regular expressions to parse out large chunks of the data and remove pieces I don't need/want. Now I'm getting down to the data I really need. The catch is, the pattern, in particular the pattern length, is dependent on a value inside of the very pattern I'm decoding.

Here are my basic building blocks:

```
hexcharpat = '([0-9A-F])';
hexbytepat = ['(' hexcharpat '{2})'];
```

Hexcharpat is a single hex character. Hexbytepat is two hex characters, or one byte of information.

Now from those building blocks, I am searching the data to match various other patterns. Many of those patterns are dependent on data within the very same pattern. Here is one example pattern (note: I'm using `...` to separate lines so all my patterns follow the same basic format in my code):

```
    pattern3 = [ ...
                 '(?<patnum>03)' ... 
                 '(?<numbytes>' hexbytepat '{1})' ...
                 '(?<data>' hexbytepat '{1,125})' ... 
               ];

   returnvalues = regexp(datastr,pattern3);
```

(bsxfun call removed for focus and clarity)

Returnvalues is then a structure with members `patnum`, `numbytes`, and `data` (Regular Expression Tokens). In the current pattern, `data` can be from 1 to 125 bytes. This is causing my `data` token to have more data than it should actually have. In reality, the length of `data` is equal to `hex2dec(numbytes)`.

A table then gets populated based on the members and values that are within the returnvalues structure.

I think I can "brute force" this by going ahead and letting `data` be too large, making a table column to put `numbytes` into (this would be a "helper column" as I otherwise don't care about this value) then revisiting the `data` column with another regexp and splitting it further based on the values of the `numbytes` column, then later in the script discarding the columns I no longer need.

All of the above will cost processor time and memory space (on very large files I might run out of memory). I would also have to do something with the "tail" of data that gets cut off as that may contain bytes for other patterns. Is there an "elegant" way to do this with a single regexp (or maybe two, without having to create a lot of variables in between)?

Note: If it can be done within regexp, don't include how to use inside of bsxfun, cellfun, and arrayfun, I will sort those out. Just pretend I want to get this regexp into a single line (or maybe two) and for some reason, adding more lines will cost me lots of processor time (which it could if I have to repeatedly call one or more of the functions mentioned). Of course, there may be a way within those functions to use something else - so if it needs to be shown in context, go for it.